# Why does loss increase when go to deeper network with multiple loss?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am using ResNet scheme to train my network architecture. After every 16 layers, I used a deconvolution and loss layer (`SoftmaxWithLoss`). When going to deeper layer, I saw that my loss (`loss3 and loss4`) increase compares with `loss2`. Why does it happen? How can I choose loss weight for each loss layer? Now, I used `loss_weight=0.1` for all loss layer, except loss_main

```
Iteration 9960, loss = 0.287316
    Train net output #0: loss_main = 0.0921776 (* 1 = 0.0921776 loss)
    Train net output #1: loss1 = 0.259363 (* 0.1 = 0.0259363 loss)
    Train net output #2: loss2 = 0.14823 (* 0.1 = 0.014823 loss)
    Train net output #3: loss3 = 0.169563 (* 0.1 = 0.0169563 loss)
     Train net output #4: loss4 = 0.21544 (* 0.1 = 0.021544 loss)
Iteration 9980, lr = 0.002
Iteration 9980, loss = 0.286957
     Train net output #0: loss_main = 0.151433 (* 1 = 0.151433 loss)
     Train net output #1: loss1 = 0.362414 (* 0.1 = 0.0362414 loss)
     Train net output #2: loss2 = 0.267339 (* 0.1 = 0.0267339 loss)
     Train net output #3: loss3 = 0.304756 (* 0.1 = 0.0304756 loss)
     Train net output #4: loss4 = 0.393892 (* 0.1 = 0.0393892 loss)
Iteration 10000, lr = 0.002
Iteration 10000, loss = 0.287502
     Train net output #0: loss_main = 0.149631 (* 1 = 0.149631 loss)
     Train net output #1: loss1 = 0.377756 (* 0.1 = 0.0377756 loss)
     Train net output #2: loss2 = 0.252874 (* 0.1 = 0.0252874 loss)
     Train net output #3: loss3 = 0.26978 (* 0.1 = 0.026978 loss)
     Train net output #4: loss4 = 0.355817 (* 0.1 = 0.0355817 loss)
```

Answer (score 4):

loss is not a monotonically decreasing function; it varies up and down.  As long as the overall *trend* is downward, training is progressing as expected.  Since you haven't given a sufficiently long base-line for the behaviour, I can't give you a full judgement on whether your model has problems.

You can adjust the loss weights in the source code, of course -- but I don't recommend it.  I think you can also override it in train_val.prototxt, but I can't find the reference at the moment.

Comment: Also, my own experience has showed me that the best thing is to keep calm and lower the learning rate :)

Comment: @Prune: Thanks. I tried to run it with 100k iterations. I saw that the loss #4 is almost bigger than another loss. Do I need to remove these last layers (which provide the last loss) in my network topology?

Comment: What ResNet are you using?  Mine has only one **loss** function.